# Loading custom config file codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am trying to load a custom config in codeigniter 3

```
$this->config->load('test')
```

test.php file is available in `application/config` folder with following content.

```
<?php

$config['item_test']='sample config item';
```

I will get the following error

> The configuration file test.php does not exist.

Codeigniter version:3.1.0

Answer (score 5):

Create new file name test.php in application/config folder.

- application/config/test.php

  ```
  <?php
      $config['gender'] = array('Male', 'Female');
  ?>
  ```
- controllers/filename.php

  ```
      class Stackoverflow extends CI_Controller{
          function __construct() {
              parent::__construct();

              $this->config->load('test'); //loading of config file
          }

          function index(){

              print_r($this->config->item('gender')); //Calling of config element.      
      }
  }
  ```
- Output

  Array ( [0] => Male [1] => Female )